# Let user select area within an existing pdf document

Tags: java, pdf, adobe-reader

The Usecase is to sign a given pdf document. I have already done the signing part, which places a visible image somewhere inside the pdf.

Now i have to let the user decide where to place the visible part of the signature.
I want to present the pdf document to the user and let him place a (draggable) rectangle somewhere inside the document.

In the end i want to get out the coordinates and the page of this rectangle.

I do not want to manipulate the pdf, just get out the coordinates and page.

I can also guarantee that adobe pdf reader is installed on the machine (windows) of the user.

Do i have to use a pdf renderer library (which?) or could i use the existing adobe pdf reader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use [jPedal](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpedal/) and draw a rectangle onto it by extending the [PdfDecoder](http://javadoc.idrsolutions.com/org/jpedal/PdfDecoder.html) and overwriting the paintComponent method.